# Plus sign at the beginning of a new line and the code compiles

Tags: c++

The code below is compilable (VS2019 and cpp.sh) whereas the last line begins with a "+". I noticed this bug when I saw that the header of my CSV file was missing a column. In C++, I just checked that this line of code is also correct : `+ 3 + 5` so it works with integers too (the + at the beginning of 3 might siganl that 3 is positive isn't it ?  but how can it work with strings ? before the '+' there's no string at all) ! Any explanation ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    
    static constexpr char s_fieldDelimiter = ';';
    static const std::string s_crlf = "\n";
    static const std::string s_regsFileHeader = std::string("Date")
        + s_fieldDelimiter + "Current Pressure (bar)"
        + s_fieldDelimiter + "Analog Flow Meter (dL/min)";
        + s_fieldDelimiter + "Analog Volume (L)";
}
```

Comment: Unary `+` is legit.  In ASCII `';'` is 59.  A *pointer* + 59 is also legit.  The C-string literal will pointer decay, and then offset by 59.  Not useful.  But that's what it'll do.

Comment: Your question is, why it compilers, although there is a semicolon at the end of the previous live `(dL/min)";`?

Comment: Have you compiled with warnings on : both msvc and clang will give a warning. E.g. msvc  https://godbolt.org/z/WcWE4rTrc gives warning C4552: '+': result of expression not used.
So it is a valid expresion it will just not lead to any functional code.

Comment: It compiles because `+ s_fieldDelimiter + "Analog Volume (L)";` is still a valid (if unused) expression. So always enable all compiler warnings and fix them.

Comment: because s_fieldDelimiter  is a char ? Ah I understand, it's pointer arithmetic isn't it ?

Comment: @Aminos You will probably get more information if you did `auto test = + s_fieldDelimiter + "Analog Volume (L)";` and see what type `test` is.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic and check "unary plus"  (promotion)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I really hate C++ although I'm a C++ developer.

Comment: @Eljay No its even more simple, the ';' on the previous line has nothing to do with it see this minimalist compiler explorer example : https://godbolt.org/z/fG63cv7K3

Comment: @Aminos Don't :)  When you use C++ as stated in the https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines it is actually pretty damn good at what it does. As said just heed the compiler warnings :) But then again I'm biased since I love it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie On online C++ compilers I got this : "PKc" when I printed typeid(test).name()

Comment: @Aminos I assumed you were using Visual Studio, and all you needed to do is hover the mouse over `test` to reveal its definition.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I know already many C++ gotchas. I'm tired of this language (and of the software industry always pushing complexity when it should advocate simplicity)

Comment: It's not the C++ gotchas that you know that make the language exciting and spicy, it's the C++ gotchas that you haven't discovered yet that keeps it fresh.  (I have a love-hate relationship with C++.)

Comment: Animos all languages have gotchas, the problem is most people don't design very well and the resulting code (independent of language) is messy as a result. And simplicity is build on top of the right abstractions, and probable years of experience (35+ in my case).

Comment: @Eljay Oh for me it is the new bits in each C++ version that really do make programming easier because the abstractions get better. (no more new/delete, range based for loops, and lately ranges, format etc.)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I should have used a std::string type for s_fieldDelimiter but I chose "char" because it's more lightweight. My case is a typo issue. Otherwise, speaking of right abstractions, using message passing is the best way to achieve inter-thread communication and that's why I like Qt's event loop system with slots/signals. I'm a C# developer too and I think it's a pity that it hasn't been implemented that threading model in the language because I often deal with code that has race conditions because of locks used to manage threads (not written by me).

Comment: For interthread communication I use lambdas (with copy captures!) and pass them to an 'executor'. Like std::async that will return a std::future. And the std::future allows me to return return values and exceptions to the caller (if needed). And I prefer that over message queing. But this is more for offline chat then the answer section ;) Hope you come to like C++ a bit more then you do now :)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Of course the ";" is the problem, as otherwise the expression had ben added to the `string` `s_regsFileHeader`. But probably you meant that the unary "+" makes it an unused expression, regardless of the ";"?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes ofcourse the premature ";" is the typo, remove that and no problem :) However the way I understood the question is that : why does it still compile and run even with the lines starting with a '+' after the ";"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field delimiter type is char (integral type), so `+ s_fieldDelimiter` is an `int` (the `+` sign is to signal that the number is positive just like in maths) and this last can be used to do pointer arithmetic since the string literal type is a "`const char*`".

Comment: No. The `+` sign is part of the arithmetic expression `+ s_fieldDelimiter`. In an arithmetic expression arguments whose types are smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int`, but that doesn't apply here). So the type of `+ s_fieldDelimiiter` is `int`, not `char`.